# How to submit form data in the same page in WordPress without reloading the page?

Tags: customization, jquery, ajax, javascript, forms

I have a custom PHP template - form. I'm trying to send this form in the same page using AJAX without reloading the page. Hide the form after submission and display the `thank you` message. This form is displayed in a modal. But what happens is that the page is still reloading.

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="modalForm" id="modalForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
        <input placeholder="Last Name*" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" required>
        <label class="error" for="name" id="lastName_error">This field is required.</label>
        <input placeholder="First Name*" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" required>
        <label class="error" for="name" id="firstName_error">This field is required.</label>
        <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" onblur="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" required>
        <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>
        <span class="validation-text">Please enter a valid email address.</span>
        <input placeholder="Mobile Number*" type="text" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="" size="11" minlength="11" maxlength="11" pattern ="^09\d{9}$" required>
        <label class="error" for="contactNumber" id="contactNumber_error">This field is required.</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="form-submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
    (function($) {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {
      // validate and process form here

      $('.error').hide();
        var name = $("input#lastName").val();
        if (lastName == "") {
        $("label#lastName_error").show();
        $("input#lastName").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var name = $("input#firstName").val();
        if (lastName == "") {
        $("label#firstName_error").show();
        $("input#firstName").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var email = $("input#Email").val();
        if (Email == "") {
        $("label#email_error").show();
        $("input#Email").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var phone = $("input#contactNumber").val();
        if (contactNumber == "") {
        $("label#contactNumber_error").show();
        $("input#contactNumber").focus();
        return false;
      }

    });

    var dataString = 'lastName='+ lastName + '&Email=' + Email + '&contactNumber=' + contactNumber;
  //alert (dataString);return false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wordpress-page/",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      $('#modalForm').html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
      .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery event is bound to elements with the class `submit`, but your submit button in the form doesn't have that class.

Either add that class to the submit button, or just target the form itself. Simply change

```
$(".button").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("#modalForm").submit(function() {
```

This will fire when the form is submitted, whether the user clicks the submit button or simply hits enter in a text field.

Comment: still the page is reloading when form submitted

Comment: Check for JavaScript errors in your browser's console in the developer tools.

Comment: unfortunately, there's no js error

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem when building my own Frontend Form.

Here's how to solve it, form has the default tendenacy to submit itself and reload. We not to stop that and use AJAX to submit the data.

A lot depends upon other functions to. But generally speaking this should work.

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 $('.error').hide();
        var name = $("input#lastName").val();
        if (lastName == "") {
        $("label#lastName_error").show();
        $("input#lastName").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var name = $("input#firstName").val();
        if (lastName == "") {
        $("label#firstName_error").show();
        $("input#firstName").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var email = $("input#Email").val();
        if (Email == "") {
        $("label#email_error").show();
        $("input#Email").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var phone = $("input#contactNumber").val();
        if (contactNumber == "") {
        $("label#contactNumber_error").show();
        $("input#contactNumber").focus();
        return false;
      }

    });

    var dataString = 'lastName='+ lastName + '&Email=' + Email + '&contactNumber=' + contactNumber;
  //alert (dataString);return false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wordpress-page/",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      $('#modalForm').html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
      .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```